# "Group" a table then order

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I don't know very well how to explain this, so I will show the result I want to get:

Test Table ->

```
id  s   q
----------
1   1   1
2   1   3
3   1   2
4   2   2
5   2   1
6   2   5
```

The result I want is this:

```
id  s   q
----------
6   2   5
4   2   2
5   2   1
2   1   3
3   1   2
1   1   1
```

I tried this query (not what I want to get):

```
SELECT id, s, q FROM test ORDER BY s, q DESC

id  s   q
----------
2   1   3
3   1   2
1   1   1
6   2   5
4   2   2
5   2   1
```

**Edit**: (Sorry, to be more clear)

If I add this row:

```
id  s   q
7   1   9
```

Now the result should be like this:

```
id  s   q
----------
7   1   9
2   1   3
3   1   2
1   1   1
6   2   5
4   2   2
5   2   1
```

---

Edit 3:
Is there a way to get this results with the same query?

Comment: After your recent edit, the query you already tried should be correct.

Comment: Do you see why your question makes no sense?

Answer (score 0):

This Query may get the result as you like:

```
SELECT id, s, q FROM test ORDER BY s DESC, q DESC
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer but what i want is like... ordering only the '**q**' (get the max value of q) but "grouping" the **s** . Note : in **s** i should put other things that numbers i think to be more clear...

Answer (score 0):

Well, one solution i found is this query (works in both results):

```
SELECT id, s, q FROM (SELECT * FROM test order by s, q DESC) x
```